# webscraping data using python beautiful soup urllib with specific data-table

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to scrape web-data from a particular web-portal. I have previously tried to learn and experiment, and had limited success using beautiful_soup and urllib.

Below is my code, which does not seem to be scraping the data I need...

```
httpLoc = 'https://uk.investing.com/currencies/forex-options'
url = requests.get(httpLoc,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
fx_data = np.array([])

content_page = soup(url.content,'html.parser')
containers = content_page.findAll('table', {'class':'vol-data-col'})
for table in containers:
    for td in table.findAll('vol-data-col'):
        #print(td.text)
        fx_data = np.append(fx_data, td.text)
```

The html code in the web-site is of the form below. I am trying to iteratively extract all the lines which have the form of the number '14.77'

```
td class="vol-data-col ng-binding ng-scope" ng-mouseover="PageSettings.setHoverInstrumentTitle(instruments[$parent.$index].title)" ng-mouseleave="PageSettings.clearHoverInstrumentTitle(instruments[$parent.$index].title)" ng-repeat="period in periods" ui-sref="currency" ng-click="PageSettings.clearHoverInstrumentTitle(); $parent.$parent.$parent.currentTenor = period.name; summaryClickFunc(period, instruments[$parent.$index]); periods[$index].active = true">14.77%</td>
```

The picture attached is how the data looks on the web-site

[image: picture of table data]

----update from comments----

I started experimenting with selenium, here's what I have:

```
import os from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Python\\chromedriver.exe")
# Initialize the webdriver session 
driver.get('https://uk.investing.com/currencies/forex-options')
# replaces "ie.navigate" 
test = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(("//*[@id='curr_table']/class"))
```

Comment: If you inspect `url.content` or `content_page`, could you see that `table` with data there?

Comment: Did you try using pd.read_html(url)

Comment: Try including the whole class string in the findAll if all relevant tables have the same classes: `"vol-data-col ng-binding ng-scope"`

Comment: @alecxe, yes I did... if I inspect the content_page, I can see the whole html page/code has been loaded.

Comment: @alexce, nope... using html5lib.parser didn't work. I don't think that was the problem.

Comment: @alecxe, sure.... here is the url : https://uk.investing.com/currencies/forex-options

Answer (score 0):

The reason you aren't getting any data is that the source code of the page does not contain the data you are attempting to get.  The data is dynamically retrieved and rendered using javascript.

To get the data, you would either have to emulate the dynamic retrieval or use a headless browser like selenium to navigate through the page and retrieve the data that way.

-- update from comments --

Given that you've selected using Selenium:

With your current approach you'll want to figure out the xpath of the table you're looking for.  You can get that by inspecting it in a browser and then selecting copy > xpath on the element.  If you'd rather just write your own xpath notation you can see how it might be done [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp)

For the table you are wanting the xpath would be something along the lines of `//table[@class="summary data-table"]`

To test various xpaths you can paste them into your browser's console as a lookup:

```
$x('//table[@class="summary data-table"]')
```

If you want a faster method you can use querySelectors or css:

```
document.querySelector('table.summary.data-table')

# output from the browser
<table class=​"summary data-table">​…​</table>​
```

For a more in depth look at how to use Selenium, you can visit https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started+with+Selenium+for+Automated+Website+Testing

Comment: thanks @B.Adler, I installed and used selenium. But 'opening' the page was as far as I could go....  any ideas? ....... import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Python\\chromedriver.exe") # Initialize the webdriver session
driver.get('https://www.investing.com/rates-bonds/germany-2-year-bond-yield-historical-data') # replaces "ie.navigate"

test = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(("//*[@id='curr_table']/class"))